# View pager displaying image only once

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have used View pager to display sliding images in my application.The code works just fine but when the user navigates to other fragments and when return back to previous fragment the images are not shown.The images in the view pager are only shown when the app starts,otherwise it is not visible.

Code

```
public class HomeScreen extends BaseFragment {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    Fragment fragment;
    private int[] images = {R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.nav_bg};
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Timer swipeTimer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_screen, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new pagerAdapter(fragmentManager, images));
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable update = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        };
        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(update);
            }
        }, 1000, 5000);

    }


    public class pagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        private int[] images;


        public pagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int[] images) {
            super(fm);
            this.images = images;

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            fragment = ImageSwitcher.newInstance(images[i]);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }
    }

}
```

Fragment Code

```
public class ImageSwitcher extends BaseFragment {

    private ImageView imageView;


    public static final ImageSwitcher newInstance(int image) {
        ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = new ImageSwitcher();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("image", image);
        imageSwitcher.setArguments(bundle);
        return imageSwitcher;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_switcher_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_switcher);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(getArguments().getInt("image"));
    }
}
```

Comment: call `initialize()` in `onCreateView` after initializing `view`.

Comment: please write the code so that i can tick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   
{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_switcher_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
 }
```

to

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_switcher_fragment, container, false);
    initialize();
    return view;
}
```